# How can I make the vertical line of certain rows thicker in LaTeX tables?

Tags: tables, tabu

I want to make a table and highlight a certain region in it using thick lines as shown below.

[image]

In my attempt to reproduce the above table, I have used the `tabu` package to make thick horizontal and vertical lines. However, there isn't any command in LaTeX to make thick vertical lines spanning given rows. Basically, I'm looking for a vertical version of `\tabucline`. Here's my code and output:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{tabu}{|[1.5pt]c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
    (-4, -4) & (-3, -4) & (-2, -4) & (-1, -4) & (0, -4) & (1, -4) & (2, -4) & (3, -4)    \\
    \hline
    (-4, -3) & (-3, -3) & (-2, -3) & (-1, -3) & (0, -3) & (1, -3) & (2, -3) & (3, -3)    \\
    \hline
    (-4, -2) & (-3, -2) & (-2, -2) & (-1, -2) & (0, -2) & (1, -2) & (2, -2) & (3, -2)    \\
    \hline
    (-4, -1) & (-3, -1) & (-2, -1) & (-1, -1) & (0, -1) & (1, -1) & (2, -1) & (3, -1)    \\
    \tabucline[1.5pt]{5-8}\hline
    (-4, 0) & (-3, 0) & (-2, 0) & (-1, 0) & (0, 0) & (1, 0) & (2, 0) & (3, 0)    \\
    \tabucline[1.5pt]{2-4}\hline
    (-4, 1) & (-3, 1) & (-2, 1) & (-1, 1) & (0, 1) & (1, 1) & (2, 1) & (3, 1)    \\
    \hline
    (-4, 2) & (-3, 2) & (-2, 2) & (-1, 2) & (0, 2) & (1, 2) & (2, 2) & (3, 2)    \\
    \hline
    (-4, 3) & (-3, 3) & (-2, 3) & (-1, 3) & (0, 3) & (1, 3) & (2, 3) & (3, 3)    \\
    \hline\tabucline[1.5pt]{1-1}
  \end{tabu}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- don't use `tabu`. It is buggy and not maintained
- instead it I suggest to use (relative new) package `tabularray`
- using it you can define all horizontal as well vertical lines in table preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines = {0.1pt}, vlines = {0.1pt},
             hline{1} = 1pt, 
             hline{5}={5-Z}{1pt}, hline{6}={2-4}{1pt}, hline{Z}={1}{1pt},
             vline{1}={1pt}, 
             vline{2}={6-Z}{1pt}, vline{5}={5}{1pt}, vline{Z}={1-4}{1pt},
             colspec =  {*{8}{Q[c, $]}},
             }
    (-4, -4) & (-3, -4) & (-2, -4) & (-1, -4) & (0, -4) & (1, -4) & (2, -4) & (3, -4)    \\
    (-4, -3) & (-3, -3) & (-2, -3) & (-1, -3) & (0, -3) & (1, -3) & (2, -3) & (3, -3)    \\
    (-4, -2) & (-3, -2) & (-2, -2) & (-1, -2) & (0, -2) & (1, -2) & (2, -2) & (3, -2)    \\
    (-4, -1) & (-3, -1) & (-2, -1) & (-1, -1) & (0, -1) & (1, -1) & (2, -1) & (3, -1)    \\
   (-4, 0)   & (-3, 0)  & (-2, 0)  & (-1, 0)  & (0, 0)  & (1, 0)  & (2, 0)  & (3, 0)     \\
    (-4, 1)  & (-3, 1)  & (-2, 1)  & (-1, 1)  & (0, 1)  & (1, 1)  & (2, 1)  & (3, 1)     \\
    (-4, 2)  & (-3, 2)  & (-2, 2)  & (-1, 2)  & (0, 2)  & (1, 2)  & (2, 2)  & (3, 2)     \\
    (-4, 3)  & (-3, 3)  & (-2, 3)  & (-1, 3)  & (0, 3)  & (1, 3)  & (2, 3)  & (3, 3)     \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: above MWE is tested with `tabularray` package version 2022C.

Comment: Wow this method is super cool! Thanks a lot. I'll look into the package documentation for further use.

Comment: You are always a talented user.

Comment: @Sebastiano, oh, thank you very much! You are so kind person!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In this environment, the key `hvlines` draws all the rules.

However, it's still possible to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz by using the Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` under the rows, columns and cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{cccccccc}
    (-4, -4) & (-3, -4) & (-2, -4) & (-1, -4) & (0, -4) & (1, -4) & (2, -4) & (3, -4)    \\
    (-4, -3) & (-3, -3) & (-2, -3) & (-1, -3) & (0, -3) & (1, -3) & (2, -3) & (3, -3)    \\
    (-4, -2) & (-3, -2) & (-2, -2) & (-1, -2) & (0, -2) & (1, -2) & (2, -2) & (3, -2)    \\
    (-4, -1) & (-3, -1) & (-2, -1) & (-1, -1) & (0, -1) & (1, -1) & (2, -1) & (3, -1)    \\
    (-4, 0)  & (-3, 0)  & (-2, 0)  & (-1, 0)  & (0, 0)  & (1, 0)  & (2, 0)  & (3, 0)     \\
    (-4, 1)  & (-3, 1)  & (-2, 1)  & (-1, 1)  & (0, 1)  & (1, 1)  & (2, 1)  & (3, 1)     \\
    (-4, 2)  & (-3, 2)  & (-2, 2)  & (-1, 2)  & (0, 2)  & (1, 2)  & (2, 2)  & (3, 2)     \\
    (-4, 3)  & (-3, 3)  & (-2, 3)  & (-1, 3)  & (0, 3)  & (1, 3)  & (2, 3)  & (3, 3)     \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [very thick] (1-|1) |- (9-|2) |- (5-|5) |- (4-|last) |- (1-|1) -- cycle ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]